# Image validation returing -1 in IE

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer

For validating image in IE, I use this code

```
var pic = document.getElementById('photo').value;
$('#image').attr('src',pic);
var imgbytes = document.getElementById('image').fileSize;
```

But imgbytes is returning -1 all the time.Why is this happening ?

Comment: this might be a race condition. Please make sure that the image is already loaded when imgbytes is evaluated

Comment: @ynh. Thank you.But I have used  while(!document.getElementById('image').fileSize)
           {
            }
before var imgbytes = document.getElementById('image').fileSize;
to make sure the image is already loaded.But still its not working.Is there any other way to make sure the image is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because the image hasn't had time to load when you query the file size. You can verify and solve this problem by switching to an asynchronous model with a callback like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('image');

img.onload = function() {
    var imgbytes = img.fileSize;
    alert(imgbytes);
};

img.src = document.getElementById('photo').value;
```

Comment: @jon.Thank you. I tried this but img.onload is not getting invoked and nothing is getting alert.ie alert(imgbytes); is not working.